# C/C++ String Error with ARM seg fault Bus error

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I have a weird problem after lots of searching and reading i have still no clue what causes the seg fault here. Please consider the following C++ code:

```
    void SensorCalibrator::getCoordinatesFromSensorMac(string in_mac, double *in_coor3D) {
    map<string, sensorInformation>::iterator itr = mac_to_sensorinfo.find(in_mac);
    if(itr != mac_to_sensorinfo.end()) {
        in_coor3D[0] = itr->second.coor[0];
        in_coor3D[1] = itr->second.coor[1];
        in_coor3D[2] = itr->second.coor[2];
    }
    else {
                in_coor3D[0] = 50.0;
                in_coor3D[1] = 55.0;
                in_coor3D[3] = 2.45;

    }
}
```

The double array in_coor3D is initialized before it is passed to the method `getCoordinatesFromSensorMac` so no worries there. 
This code has no problem on an Intel or AMD 64 Bit architecture however on an ARM v7l (Raspberry Pi 3) it crashes with a "Segmentation Fault" (g++ v5) or a "Bus Error" (g++ v4.7). Here is the corresponding GDB backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x9999999a) at malloc.c:2966
2966    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
0  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x9999999a) at malloc.c:2966
1  0x7679fb90 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6
2  0x00053b64 in WiPiDevicesHandler::setSensorCoordinates (this=0xf24e0, sens=0x110458) at ../WiPiDevicesHandler.cc:437
```

The line 437 is the call to the `getCoordinatesFromSensorMac` method. 
I inserted some debug `printf` into the method and it seems that the string `in_mac` is causing the problem, and here is what i have found out so far:

1. The string `in_mac` is fine before the method is called and inside the method.
2. if `in_mac` is found in the `std:map` (inside the
   if) then the method does not crash.
3. if `in_mac` is not found in
   the `std:map` (inside the else) then the string `in_mac` is gone,
   meaning that a `printf` with `in_mac` crashes. GDB also says "cannot access memory at 0x99999a" for the string.

As i have mentioned the same method has no problems on a AMD 64Bit Architecture. My guess is that on the ARM Architecture string is moved to an address which is considered as "freed" and the crash happens and also i suspect that this comes from the `std:map find` function. 
Beyond that i have no clue what causes this crash. Do you have any ideas ? 
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the typo:

```
in_coor3D[3] = 2.45;
```

it should most likely be:

```
in_coor3D[2] = 2.45;
```

Comment: Oh man, this is really really embarrassing. Thank you so much.